# Docker images/containers are not shown after dive tool installation

Tags: docker

I recently tried to install via snap, dive tool https://github.com/wagoodman/dive regarding image layering inspection.

OS info:
**buntu 22.04.1 LTS**

After the installation i noticed that `docker images` and `docker container ls` commands return nothing as response while all the images and containers still exist under /var/lib/docker

Tried to restart the daemon but the problem still occurs.

Does anyone encountered something similar?

Quick update: i think evil snap did the magic: after the snap installation of dive `docker info` shows as as Docker Root Dir **Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker**  instead of **/var/lib/docker**. I think i have to change that somehow

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sure, changed to text description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that snap installation of dive somehow destroyed the Docker root dir path. While inspecting with `docker info` i noticed that Docker Root Dir: has changed to `Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker instead of /var/lib/docker.`

I reverted the path using

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket

sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

then chnaged the **ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock** to **ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /var/lib/docker -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock**

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Worked fine.

Hope helps.

p.s. I really don't know what's wrong with snap. It gave me a lot of trouble in many scenarios in the past.